# Using pip3 with sudo permission problem in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, python3, pip

I have *Python3* and *Python2* and also `pip` and `pip3` for various python version package installation.

I want install a **ZMQ** library in Python 2 and 3, I did it in python2 as well with the following line:

```
sudo pip install zmq
```

---

But when I using `pip3` for **ZMQ** installation on Python3 I have a problem:

```
$ pip3 install zmq
Collecting zmq
Collecting pyzmq (from zmq)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/94/e8/6b39ec62b4f7821eeefd69e0c1ddfd56744cd6613f8216fc972cfc8d7765/pyzmq-17.1.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: pyzmq, zmq
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zmq'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

---

Then when I used sudo before `pip3`:

```
$ sudo pip3 install zmq
sudo: pip3: command not found
```

---

[NOTE]:

```
$ pip --version
pip 18.0 from /home/benyamin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)

$ pip3 --version
pip 18.0 from /home/benyamin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)

$ which pip
/home/benyamin/.local/bin/pip

$ which pip3
/home/benyamin/.local/bin/pip3

$ sudo which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip

$ sudo which pip3
$ # no output
```

It seems that my `pip` is for Python3.6!

---

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: pip3 is installed in user scope. You have to install pip3 globally. or you have to install zmq in user scope. Try `pip3 install --user zmq`

Comment: @dedunumax how can I install pip3 globally?

Comment: @dedunumax I did it : `pip3 install --<my-user> zmq` but I confronted with permission denided again

Comment: Dont add your user name just type user

Comment: Did you try it with just user?

Comment: @dedunumax yes, I vote up your comment, but I have a new problem: `It seems that my pip is for Python3.6!`

Comment: @dedunumax Both `pip` and `pip3` are for Python3.6!

Comment: I extremely recommend virutalenv. That way you will keep all your modules separate.

Answer (score 1):

First remove your local `pip`:

```
/home/benyamin/.local/bin/pip3 uninstall pip
```

Install it using `apt`:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

or for "python2":

```
sudo apt install python-pip
```

then run:

```
sudo pip3 install zmq
```

you can also update `pip` using:

```
sudo pip3 install pip --upgrade
```

---

Alternative solution is to creat an alias:

```
alias pip3='sudo /home/benyamin/.local/bin/pip3'
```

Comment: With this instruction can I have both pip for Python2 and pip3 for Python3 simultaneously?

Comment: Yep, just install both of them...

Comment: when I did `/home/benyamin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip uninstall pip
` confront with `bash: /home/benyamin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip: Is a directory`

Comment: @BenyaminJafari what about this one: `/home/benyamin/.local/bin/pip3 uninstall pip`

Comment: `bash: /home/benyamin/.local/bin/pip3: No such file or directory`

Comment: Outpt in 2 ta dastor ro bezar `which pip3` va `which pip2`, bara kodom version az python mikhay nasb koni baste ro?

Comment: Okay, let me know the output of `which pip3` and `sudo which pip3`

Comment: which pip3 output is  `/usr/bin/pip3` now.

Comment: what about `sudo which pip3`?

Comment: `which pip3`  --> `/usr/bin/pip3`  , `which pip`  -->  `/home/benyamin/.local/bin/pip`

Comment: `ls -l /usr/bin/pip3` and `ls -l $HOME/.local/bin/pip ` without `sudo`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81266/discussion-between-ravexina-and-benyamin-jafari).

Answer (score 1):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip   
sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Create a symbolic link at `/home/benyamin/.local/bin/pip3` which references to file `/usr/local/bin/pip3`.

```
cd /home/benyamin/.local/bin/
rm pip3
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip3 /home/benyamin/.local/bin/pip3
```

Check location of the pip3 executable file and pip3 version.

```
which pip3  
pip3 --version
```

Install zmq.

```
python3 -m pip install --user zmq
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I update my question in NOTE section, please read that ...